# Maintain a stack for content of div tag

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I am working with a datatable. On row click, I am able to open a details page in the same div as that of the datatable using `divname.load(@url.action('')`.

Now I want to provide a close button on that details page and load the previous data table div using jquery.

Can this be done by maintaining a stack of div tags somehow? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

**Just an Idea**

1. Create different `div` all the time when you load a page.
2. Hide the old one when you load a new page.
3. While closing the current one hide the current and show the one previously opened.

You can give Id to each div in a sequence so that showing and hiding is simpler.

Like the first `div` gets id **div_0** and the second `div` id is **div_1** and so on.

 So when you are closing the div having id  **div_1** you know that you have to show **div_0**